# center element within another, while parent specifies position: absolute?

Tags: css, position, css-position, vertical-alignment

I'm working with this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BY3tz/1/

Notice when you remove the `position`, `left`, and `top` properties from the `dotParent` CSS class, the black dot is centered within the box.

I'm looking for a way to keep the black dot centered (vertically and horizontally) while **leaving the 3 properties mentioned above** in place so that I can change the `left` and `top` properties to position the box anywhere, and the black dot will remain centered.

Is this possible? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong with my `dot` class?

Comment: originally the `vertical-align` works because of `display: table-cell`. When you add `position: absolute`, it loses properties associated with being `table-cell`, hence the dot move towards the top (not vertically centered)

Comment: Thank you @Ejay for the explanation. That makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some tweaks to the `.dot` class:

```
.dot {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-left: -5px; // Half of the width * (-1)
    margin-top: -5px; // Half of the height * (-1)
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BY3tz/2/

Comment: I have one more small issue. Looking at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/GFHTB/3/, is it possible to put the text back inside while **leaving** `position: absolute` on the `content` div? Notice how it works fine without the `position` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Added dot wrapper so `.dot` is relative to new wrapper,

```
<div class="dotParent">
    <div class="dot-wrapper">
        <div class="dot"></div>
    </div><!-- end dot-wrapper -->
</div>
```

New Styles.

```
.dot-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Added to .dot class

```
.dot {
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    left:45%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BY3tz/5/

Comment: Thanks! While this works perfectly as well, I think I'm going to go with @Kaloyan Ivanov's solution because it did not require additional HTML and an additional CSS class.

Answer (score 1):

Change the position attribute in the dotParent div to "Relative". Since its the parent Div, it needs to be positioned as Relative in order for its children to take it as a reference point.

```
.dotParent {
    position: relative;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 68px;
    width: 68px;
    border: 1px solid Black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BY3tz/6/